# How to choose the right column types and sizes for a table I am planning to use a lot

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, type-conversion

I want to create a table that I plan on using and reading from and writing to a lot. All the fields in my table will either be text, a number, or a date. Which column types should I use and what size should I make them?

Should I use VARCHAR or NVARCHAR for my text columns?
Should I make them Varchar(Max) or a limit that I don't see any field reasonably being longer like Varchar(1000). Should I try to guess the field length for each column or can I just do varchar(1000) for everything?

And for numbers what is the best data type? Is it numeric? How do I set everything to a precision of 3. No more, no less. Or is that unnecessary?

And for my last field, date what is the best date type to use? I want all my dates to be something like 1/1/2019 01:23:55.777

And to create this table, all I have to do is something like this with the correct data types and sizes that I want?

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);
```

And then after I create the table, to create the columns I want to index on, I just run the following?

```
CREATE INDEX OrderNumber
ON Table (OrderNumber);
```

Does it matter if I do this before my table has any data in it? Also, I don't know a lot about indexes, trying to do my research right now, but is it safe to assume to create indexes out of the columns that I will be using to join? For example, in this table I am creating I am going to join it to two other tables, one by OrderNumber and one by TicketNumber. So I plan to use those columns for my index, is that correct? And do the same on those other tables.

Comment: The data types, and sizes, completely depends on what you're going to be storing. I doubt, however, you're going to need `MAX`, as I doubt there's anyone out there whose name is made of over 2 billion characters. You know your data better than us, and we don't have any examples; and then they're only examples and may not accurately provide the scope of the data you have.

Comment: NVARCHAR is better, incase you have someone whose name is spelled in a different language. VARCHAR would return a '?', NVARCHAR would return correct. It looks like DATETIME is the data type that you want for your date. For numbers, if they are always whole numbers, then use INT, as long as that number isn't an extremely large number.

Comment: " I want all my dates to be something like 1/1/2019 01:23:55.777 "  Dates don't have formats.  This belongs in the presentation layer ... DON'T be tempted to store the dates as a string.

Comment: Just a side note, when communicating dates, avoid ambiguity.  Rather than typing 1/1/2019 you might choose 1/22/2019 or even M/d/yyyy

Comment: Or better yet, @JohnCappelletti use an unambiguous format like `yyyy-MM-dd`/`2019-01-01` ;)

Comment: The "best" data type for any column is the data type that most closely matches the profile of the data the column will be storing, with adequate room for currently unexpected growth. So, for instance, I tend to prefer `bigint` to `int` for ID columns, because you don't want to be woken up at 3 AM to find you've added one too many rows and now you have to refactor every SSIS package and stored procedure that touches the table. But, as noted already, only you and your team can really know. Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Larnu I was referring to his desired format. OP may want dates DISPLAYED as m/d/yyyy or d/m/yyyy   hard to tell by the sample

Comment: The order number and the ticket number looks something like this '9324239'. Is it better to store this as text or as a number (even though technically it is kinda text)? Will storing it as a number lead to faster joining and lookups or whatever? So would you guys recommend using INT to store these order numbers? And what about dollar values? Numeric? Or is there a currency field that is better?

Answer (score 1):

For the `ID` column `INT` works. You can use the qualifiers `IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` which will automatically assign the next value when inserting a new record. You simply leave the column out of your `INSERT` statement and the value gets assigned.

In general, I would recommend `NVARCHAR` over `VARCHAR` for anything that can have characters beyond the ASCII set. That is, any language other than English.

For the date, if it's for tracking the date of inserts or updates, then I would recommend using `DATETIME2` which is aligned with the newer SQL standards than `DATETIME`.

As for your indices, that depends on how you access your data. Primary keys are automatically indexed, so that's not an issue. So if the `ordernumber` is the primary key for the `order` table, it will be indexed anyway.

Comment: I should add that the maximum length for a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` column generally should depend on your application. For example, as others have pointed out, you don't expect a 1000 character first name, and if you use `NVARCHAR(1000)` then you may run into problems with your UI. So use a maximum that makes sense in that regard. However, from a storage point of view, `NVARCHAR(50) = 'JOE'` uses exactly the same space as `NVARCHAR(10000) = 'JOE'`

Comment: EDIT: Also the order number and the ticket number looks something like this '9324239'. I am not creating it as I go, I am reading it from another table. Is it better to store this as text or as a number (even though technically it is kinda text)? Will storing it as a number lead to faster joining and lookups or whatever?

Comment: If the order number and ticket number can only be "numbers" i.e. integers, then store them as integers. It will lead to better performance both in the amount of storage needed and lookup performance. It also sorts properly since in a text field, `10` sorts before `9` (text sorts character-by-character). HOWEVER, if you can have values like `0010`, then it _might_ be a candidate for a text field (although I would probably still use `INT` and add the leading `0`s as part of the query).